# Outputting a randomly filled array list multiple times with different results each time?

Tags: java, sorting, random, arraylist, permutation

So im filling an array with random numbers from 1-10 by using a second array to fetch the numbers from. I need to get 10 different results, each run outputting a different random array list. How could i do that? Right now if i try to output it more than once, it just out puts the same numbers over and over again. I need 10 different outputs.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> numbers =new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Integer> numbers2 =new ArrayList<Integer>();

    Random generator = new Random();


    for(int i = 0; i<=10;i++) {
        numbers2.add(i);
    }

   for(int z = 0; z<=10; z++){

    for(int i = 0; i<=1000;i++) {

        int x = generator.nextInt(10)+1;
        if (!numbers.contains((numbers2.get(x)))) {
            numbers.add(numbers2.get(x));;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(numbers);
}
```

}

Comment: You can tremendously improve the random-set generator by implementing it as a shuffle. What you've got now is not guaranteed to generate a complete set, and emphatically is not efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the same `numbers` array at each of the 10 iterations. By the time the first iteration is over, the array already has every digit from 1 to 10 so the if condition will evaluate to false and nothing will be added to it.

So you need to create a new `numbers` array for each of the 10 iterations, or remove its contents after printing it.

Comment: didn't work :/, still repeating the same set of number each time when i try to output numbers 10 times, wanting to get different numbers each time.

Comment: What do you mean you try to output numbers 10 times? Do you run the program 10 times or have 10 print statements? Can you edit your question with the exact code you are using?

Comment: 10 print statements, and i edited the code, this is the code that gives me the same 10 statements with the exact same numbers each time.